# SQL query for graph same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with these fields

```
EVENT timestamp
SOND int (temperature sond) 1-13
TEMP float (temperature of sond)
```

The `EVENT` is different for each sond because the record for each sond is inserted only on change.

I need a query to display the values as follow

```
EVENT / SOND / TEMP (last value of previous event)
```

For example, let's say that I have these rows stored:

```
15:30 / 1 / 25.50

15:31 / 2 / 31.00

15:35 / 1 / 26.00
```

I want to display these results

```
15:30 / 1 / 25.50

15:30 / 2 / DEFAULT OR 0

15:31 / 1 / 25.50

15:31 / 2 / 31.00

15:35 / 1 / 26.00

15:35 / 2 / 31.00
```

Thanks

```
SELECT      e.EVENT,
            s.SONDA,
            (SELECT CT1.TEMP
             FROM     CT_SONDE CT1
             WHERE    CT1.EVENT<= e.EVENT
             AND      CT1.SONDA = s.SONDA
             ORDER BY CT1.EVENT DESC
             LIMIT 1) as TEMPERATURA
from       (SELECT   CT2.EVENT
            from     CT_SONDE CT2
            GROUP BY CT2.EVENT) e
cross join (SELECT   CT3.SONDA
            FROM     CT_SONDE CT3
            GROUP BY CT3.SONDA) AS s
ORDER BY    e.EVENT, s.SONDA
```

Comment: Specify Sql system please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query:

```
select      e.event,
            s.sonda,
            (select   temp
             from     ct_sonde
             where    event <= e.event
             and      sonda = s.sonda
             order by event desc
             limit 1) as temp
from       (select   event
            from     ct_sonde
            group by event) e
cross join (select   sonda
            from     ct_sonde
            group by sonda) s
order by    e.event, s.sonda
```

The  `limit 1` is non-standard SQL, but does the trick in MySql for finding the most recent predecessor for an event that has no explicit temperature for a certain value of *sonda*.

Still that correlated sub query can be a killer for performance. So maybe the next solution could have better performance:

#### Alternative using variables

Using variables in MySql queries can be risky as some assumptions must be made on the order in which the engine processes the different parts of the query and determines the (intermediate) order:

```
select event, sonda, temp
from (
    select case when temp is null and @sonda = sonda 
                then @temp
                else @temp := temp
           end as temp,
           @sonda := sonda as sonda,
           event
    from (   
        select      log.temp,
                    s.sonda,
                    e.event
        from       (select   sonda
                    from     ct_sonde
                    group by sonda) s
        cross join (select   event
                    from     ct_sonde
                    group by event) e
        left join   ct_sonde log
                on  log.event = e.event
                and log.sonda = s.sonda
        order by    s.sonda, e.event
        limit 50000000
    ) as phase1
) as phase2
order by event, sonda
```

The `limit 50000000` is an extra precaution to make the engine obey the inner `order by` clause. That number must be at least the number of records that would be returned without that clause; it should not really eliminate records from the result. The query on "phase1" depends on this order as it uses variables to keep track of the current *sonda* and latest *temp* for that *sonda*.

Finally the outer query re-orders the result (if you need this) by *event* and then by *sonda*. Again, there is no absolute guarantee that this always works, as the SQL engine is free to re-order intermediate result sets and evaluate variables in any order.

Comment: @RobertoPatti, did this solve your issue? Could you give some feed-back?

Comment: i think to find the error. but now i have another problem. In the table there are 15.000 record moltiply for each SOND (12) is 180.000 records. How i can optimize the table for the query time? thanks

Comment: Do you have a separate table with the 12 values for SOND? That would be good to have. I will update my answer later today, to use the extra info you have given (MySql).

Comment: I added an alternative, which may or may not be helpful. Still, if you have 180.000 records, do you really need all of them in a specific result set? Who will look at 180.000 figures in a report!? Would you not filter by some condition? In that case you should apply that filter inside the query, at an early stage.